# Winforms Webbrowser .NET 3.5 rendering on CE device

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, windows-ce

I am building a CE based Web Wrapper and I have a problem whereby occasionally when I am loading a html table, the webbrowser control gets so far before stopping rendering. I know that I have received all the data as when I then interact with the page it then redraws and all the content appears.

Does anyone know what the best way to solve this is? calling refresh or invalidate on the control does not seem to trigger the action that I want or expect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420027/webbrowser-does-not-display-page-until-an-event-occurs/34795195#34795195](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420027/webbrowser-does-not-display-page-until-an-event-occurs/34795195#34795195)

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to resolve this issue now and I am just sharing my experience in case anyone comes across this issue. If there is a better solution then please let me know :)

The simplest way I found of solving this is to actually implement a bit of JavaScript in the webapp, by no means a direct fix, however it could be adapted by injects a bit of code in the request. Essentially create a hidden div and then display and hide it using JavaScript to force the browser to re-render.

I fully admit this is an ugly solution, but it's worked for what we want. Alternatives are very much welcome which address the core issue (upgrade device or browser is not possible at this time)